# Access resources in the same directory from .htaccess file with different URL

Tags: .htaccess

Can I do in .htaccess file to use resources in DOCUMENT ROOT from a domain ends with /bla ? So what I want is something like this, I want to access **www.domain.com/bla/** but the resources or contents are the same with **www.domain.com** with the URL is always **www.domain.com/bla**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/bla/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /bla/$1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^bla/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but how to always keep the url /bla in every page? Because when I move to another page, the url changed to www.domain.com/page. I want the previous url always followed by the page I move, like www.domain.com/bla/page. 
However, can you tell me where should I learn about htaccess?

Comment: ok try my updated rules now. For good reference on mod_rewrite use http://askapache.com